# Querying with two parameters

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to query for  `preference=_primary` and `routing=id2`. I tried this:

```
GET /bookshop/book/_search_shards?preference=_primary?routing=route2
```

But I get error:

```
"error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "no Preference for [_primary?routing=route2]"
         }
```

**How to build correctly single querying primary shards for route value `route2`?**

Comment: You have two `?` the second one should be `&`

Comment: Thanks. Of course :) Upvoted.

Comment: Did it work in the end?

Comment: Yes it has showed only the primary shards